# Link a git repo from one project to another Azure DevOps Project

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

I have a Azure DevOps project (**Project A**), which has a repository **Repo A**.
I have a different project (**Project B**). Now, I would like to "link" Repo A to Project B.

I am aware that I can clone Repo A to Project B, but my specific requirement is to simply use Repo A in Project B and not to create a clone.

How to do this in Azure DevOps?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Can you explain the need? Maybe a alternative solution exists.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but would a submodule work?

Comment: Thank you. I realized forking is the solution for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements of your development process with two linked repositories are not clear. However, you can fork Repo A into Repo B of Project B and move changes between them. Documentation: [Forks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think forking works for what I am looking for.